# How can I add Google Closure UI components to a control in a Google Map?

Tags: google-closure

I am creating an application which uses a google map, V3 of the API. However it does not let me add any Closure UI components to the DIVs which represent the Custom Controls of the map. Has anyone got any hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps lets you add arbitrary elements as controls. For example:

`map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(element);`

That element, which you have a reference to, can be decorated or rendered into using Closure, as you would any other. I've used this and it works great.